yt-dlp is using \\ in path… sometimes
I'm new to yt-dlp and have been experimenting with it to see how it works. I've got it working for the most part, but recently ran into another issue that I can't figure out.
After executing my PowerShell script, I can see that yt-dlp.exe is trying to use double backslashes (\\) in my path variable\object.
ERROR: unable to open for writing: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Downloads\\yt-dlp\\Splinter Cell - Blacklist (Perfectionist-Ghost-NoKO) 
(Centerstrain01)\\Splinter Cell - Blacklist (Perfectionist-Ghost-NoKO) - s01e01 - Splinter Cell Blacklist  PerfectionistGhostNo Knockouts  Part 1 Mission #1 
Safehouse.f623.mp4.part-Frag126.part'

The main thing I noticed is that the videos in the playlist are using pipe (|) and double quotes (") characters in the video title. I can't say for sure this is the issue, however it's what I suspect.
At first, I tried using the --restrict-filenames switch for yt-dlp, and I think that worked in one of my tests, but not anymore. I recall it using underscore (_) characters in the Filename portion of my output.
Command ran through a ForEach-Object loop:
yt-dlp.exe --config-location $($_.ConfigFile) -P $($_.Path) --output $($_.Filename) $($_.URL) $($_.Action) $($_.Range)

My Input Values displayed in POSH, and each of these are double quoted in my CSV file like so: "string","string","string", etc.
Path:       D:\Downloads\yt-dlp\Splinter Cell - Blacklist (Perfectionist-Ghost-NoKO) (Centerstrain01)
Filename:   Splinter Cell - Blacklist (Perfectionist-Ghost-NoKO) - s01e%(playlist_index)02d - %(title)s.%(ext)s
URL:        https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjRn9IUTqS1CxvMXdg2emcwDgi66ln5jo

I'm using the latest version of yt-dlp.exe downloaded from GitHub here:
https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp?tab=readme-ov-file#installation > Windows X64
Product version: 2024.03.10
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
UPDATE:
I decided to perform the following additional tests to rule out the CSV/POSH Import aspect:
TEST 1
Results: Created the PATH folder correctly; nothing downloaded.
yt-dlp.exe --config-location "D:\Downloads\config_playlist.conf" `
    -P "D:\Downloads\yt-dlp\Splinter Cell - Blacklist (Perfectionist-Ghost-No Knockouts) (Centerstrain01)" `
    --output "Splinter Cell - Blacklist (Perfectionist-Ghost-No Knockouts) - s01e%(playlist_index)02d - %(title)s.%(ext)s" `
    "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjRn9IUTqS1CxvMXdg2emcwDgi66ln5jo"

TEST 2 - added the --restrict-filenames switch
Results: Created the PATH folder correctly; ironically, downloaded only video 4 & 5 thumbnails as .webp files using my Output filename structure.
yt-dlp.exe --config-location "D:\Downloads\config_playlist.conf" `
    -P "D:\Downloads\yt-dlp\Splinter Cell - Blacklist (Perfectionist-Ghost-No Knockouts) (Centerstrain01)" `
    --output "Splinter Cell - Blacklist (Perfectionist-Ghost-No Knockouts) - s01e%(playlist_index)02d - %(title)s.%(ext)s" --restrict-filenames `
    "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjRn9IUTqS1CxvMXdg2emcwDgi66ln5jo"

Example of one of the two files created in the 2nd test:
"D:\Downloads\yt-dlp\Splinter Cell - Blacklist (Perfectionist-Ghost-No Knockouts) (Centerstrain01)\Splinter Cell - Blacklist (Perfectionist-Ghost-No Knockouts) - s01e04 - Splinter_Cell_-_Blacklist_Perfectionist_Ghost_NOKO_Part_4_Mission_4_Private_Estate.webp"

This leads me to believe that the video titles are the likely culprit...
My Config File looks like this:
-S "ext"
--sub-lang "en*" --write-auto-subs --embed-subs
--embed-thumbnail
--embed-metadata
--ffmpeg-location "D:\Tools\ffmpeg\bin"


Try specifying paths and filenames using APOSTROPHE quoting instead of QUOTATION MARK quoting. Just like in bash, strings using APOSTROPHE quoting are not extrapolated (expanded).

Hi lit,
Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, the apostrophe (single quote) will not work for this case. I ran into more issues in my testing. The single quotes caused all commas to be seen as a separate field.
Many videos have titles containing commas, and there needed for pulling a nonsequential order of videos in a playlist.
Some examples include:
Titles:
"This, That and The Other - Performance and Tutorial"
"This'n'That Card Trick Revealed"
"OneNote, Forms and Publisher"
Range of videos by index number:
"1,3-5,11,15-17"
Thanks again, lit.
